# Typescript accepts return in function that should return void

Tags: reactjs, typescript

When creating a function like this:

```
let func : (name: string) => void; 
func = function (name) {
    return "s";
}
```

Everything works fine even thought it should give an error while in those situations:

```
let func : (name: string) => number; 
func = function (name) {
    return "s"; // error
}

function func (name: string) : void {
    return "s"; // error
}
```

an error is shown, why does it work this way?

Comment: A return type of `void` doesn't necessarily mean that the function returns `undefined`. Rather, it means that the return type is unimportant because it's **designed not to be used by and should not be used by** other code. You might be interested in using `void | undefined` as the return type if you want to prevent values other than `undefined` from being returned, but also want to permit the lack of a return statement. See https://tsplay.dev/WoAAlN